# Implement open telemetry with NextJS (how to trigger tracing.js with build version)

Tags: next.js, open-telemetry

According to this [post](https://signoz.io/blog/opentelemetry-nextjs/), after implementing OpenTelemetry, I can spin up the service with:

```
node tracing.js
```

From this [post](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server), the custom-server method will remove important optimizations, that's why I am wondering if there is a way to implement open telemetry without this custom-server? Because for production, the app is running with:

```
next build
next start -p $PORT
```

How to build the app and use tracing.js as an entrypoint with the build version?
For node-js, I can use the following code in node.js

```
node -r tracing.js index.js
```

can I achieve a similar goal with NextJS?